# Very slow numba CUDA in python

Tags: python, numba

I run this simple code into numba cuda, and it find very slow.
Any idea of the bottleneck ?

```
   @cuda.jit('int32(float64,  float64, int32)', device=True)
   def mandelbrot_numbagpu(creal,cimag,maxiter):
       real = creal
       imag = cimag
       for n in range(maxiter):
           real2 = real*real
           imag2 = imag*imag
           if real2 + imag2 > 4.0:
               return n
           imag = 2* real*imag + cimag
           real = real2 - imag2 + creal
       return 0



   @cuda.jit
   def        mandelbrot_set_numbagpu(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,width,height,maxiter,n3,r1,r2):
      for i in range(width):
         for j in range(height):
            n3[i,j] = mandelbrot_numbagpu(r1[i],r2[j],maxiter)


   r1 = np.linspace(-2.0,0.5,1000, dtype=np.float )
   r2 = np.linspace(-1.25,1.25,1000, dtype=np.float)
   n3 = np.zeros((1000,1000),  dtype=np.uint8)

   %timeit mandelbrot_set_numbagpu(-2.0,0.5,-1.25,1.25,1000,1000,80,n3,r1,r2)
   #1 loops, best of 3: 4.84 s per loop
```

If I run on JIT, it is  10 times faster !....

Comment: perhaps in your nested loops with recursion for each loop

Comment: I could be wrong here, but you're running it in serial on a single GPU I think? Do you don't need `cuda.grid` instead of the two loops http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/kernels.html#thread-positioning

Comment: (GPU core, not GPU...)

Comment: You mean  n3 =  cuda.grid(1000, 1000)  ?
is it GPU array ?  Believe there is some memory transfer issues with numpy table....

Comment: I don't know exactly what I mean unfortunately. I've never used numba and cuda myself. I'd guess you get `i` and `j` from `grid` and use those to call `mandelbrot_numbagpu`? It might be easier to try to use the `vectorize` interface though?

Answer (score 4):

The issue that with Numba/CUDA (and I think with CUDA) in general, your functions aren't supposed to iterate over an array. Instead they're supposed to deal with a single array element, and the Numbda/CUDA handler assigns a whole bunch of array elements to a whole bunch of GPU cores and thus everything happens quickly and in parallel. This is [all documented](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.23.1/cuda/kernels.html).

Unfortunately it means that you can't just change `@jit` to `@cuda.jit` but that you have to adapt it.

The following works:

```
# mandelbrot_numbagpu as before...

# I've removed some of the useless arguments for simplicity
@cuda.jit
def mandelbrot_set_numbagpu(n3,r1,r2,maxiter):
    # numba provides this function for working out which element you're
    # supposed to be accessing
    i,j = cuda.grid(2)
    if i<n3.shape[0] and j<n3.shape[1]: # check we're in range
        # do work on a single element
        n3[i,j] = mandelbrot_numbagpu(r1[i],r2[j],maxiter)
```

You then call it as

```
# you assign a number of threads, and split it into blocks
# this is all in the documentation!
import math
threadsperblock = (16,16)
blockspergrid_x = math.ceil(n3.shape[0] / threadsperblock[0])
blockspergrid_y = math.ceil(n3.shape[1] / threadsperblock[1])
blockspergrid = (blockspergrid_x, blockspergrid_y)

mandelbrot_set_numbagpu2[blockspergrid,threadsperblock](n3,r1,r2,80)
# n3, r1 and r2 are defined as before
```

On my PC this produces a 3800x speed improvement. I don't know how that compares to the equivalent CPU program.